# Sightly: Adding components dynamically on wcmmode edit

Tags: javascript, angular, aem, sightly

I am using sightly and angular 4 for my AEM project. I have a requirement in which i have a parent component, and on the edit mode, the parent component should have a button to add another pre existing component. I am able to do this without slightly, with this function,

```
addCmp: function () {
    var component = this;
    var cmp = CQ.WCM.getEditable(component.path + '/par/*');
    var flCmp = CQ.WCM.getComponentConfig('path of the component to be added');
    if (cmp.createParagraph(flCmp) === null) {
         console.warn('Could not add pane to this paragraph, check design settings');
    }
}
```

and this function is present in dialog.js in clientlibs-wcmedit of my component.
How to achieve this same functionality with sightly and Angular 4 in AEM

Comment: Why would you add a button to add an accordion if you could as well use ootb drag and drop to drop the component in the container? Overlays for "improving" product features is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}"` to conditionally render something only in edit mode. See also https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#211-identifiers and https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/htl/using/global-objects.html

Comment: but the requirement here is to have a component which can add more components in edit mode. In the real time scenario we have here, we are supposed to be having a parent component which can add accordians on click of a button in the dialog. The author will just have to click on the "add accordian" button to add an accordian into the parent component

Comment: @AnilSimon you're mixing concerns here. HTL/Sightly is used for server-side rendering. You can use it to render a button or trigger area in edit mode. The rest will need to be handled client-side (in Javascript).

Comment: @AnilSimon AEM provides this already out-of-the-box? You add a "parent" component to your pages paragraph system (also called parsys). This component is also marked as a "container" component. This container component itself does have a parsys. You can define which components are allowed in the container components parsys. For example your accordion components. Then it is an easy matter of dragding-and-dropping the according component, double clicking on the parsys etc. I feel that you are making it too complicated which is not a good idea with AEM.